# Understanding read() Operation in C?

Tags: c, file

I have this code:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
char buf[len];
size_t count =0;
while (count < len){
    size_t_nbytes = read (fd, buf+len, len-count);
    if(nbytes==0){
        len=count;
         break;
     }
    count +=nbytes;
}
```

The part I don´t understand is the len-count in the read() function. len-count is the size of the block I would like to read. Which in the first loop is len. So everything I want to read. Can I just replace it with len? The loop should probably only loop once anyway? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it "probably" should loop once, don't bet on it, better just handle it:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
char buf[len];
size_t count =0;
while (count < len){
    size_t_nbytes = read (fd, buf+count, len-count);
                               //  ^^  use count instead of len
    if(nbytes==0){
         break;
     } else if (nbytes == -1) {
         perror("read");
         break;
     }
    count +=nbytes;
}
```

Now, the first iteration, if e.g. len is 100, the read call becomes

```
 read (fd, buf+0, 100-0);
```

If this happened to read 50 bytes, the next round becomes

```
  read (fd, buf+50, 100-50);
```

Which is exactly what you'd want.

Comment: So even if the file is longer than len and I would like to read a block the size len, there is no guaranty read will actually read all len bytes but maybe only size_t_nbytes < len?

Comment: @HansEn I believe for normal files, read(), will read the entire length you pass in if the file is that big on most unixes, though I can't find any references that guarantees that. Anyhow, if you e.g. open files in /proc/ on linux, or a named pipe, you can most certainly get short read()'s. So better to just handle it.

Comment: The man page on OS X states *"The system guarantees to read the number of bytes requested if the descriptor references a normal file that has that many bytes left before the end-of-file, but in no other case."* and I always thought this is true in general. But I could not find that in the POSIX specification http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/read.html. It would be interesting to know if a "short read" can actually happen for a regular file on any Unix platform.

Comment: That's why there's a macro of TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html

Comment: @zoska That serves another purpose, although it's possible you can get a short read if a signal is caught, and you have not enabled restartable system calls.